# Pass-through SSL with HAProxy and vhosts on same IP

Tags: ssl, haproxy

Can i pass-through SSL with HAProxy to a vhost that shares ip with other vhosts?

I try

```
frontend https
bind *:443 #ssl
mode tcp
default_backend port_443

backend port_443
mode tcp
server web42 www.example.com
```

But i see the default webserver, not www.example.com

I could do SNI on frontend, but how to say to backend - this is for domain www.example.com?

```
server web1 www.example.com:443 sni str(www.example.com) verify none
```

doesn't work either.

To make it clear, webserver www.default.com, www.example.com, www.example.net all have same IP and Port, e.g. 10.0.1.10:443
Apache/ngix chooses the right vhost with SNI.

Problem is still not solved. Here some graphic

```
                                   --------------------
                                  |(All 10.0.1.10:443)
www2.example.com:443 -> HaProxy ->|www.default.com <- Apache vhost default
                                  |www.example.com
                                  |www.example.net 
                                   --------------------
```

I would like to reach www.example.com (with mode tcp)

If i have private keys of www.example.com and www.example.net. Can i reach www.example.net (when user input is www.example.com) without security problems?

Answer (score 5):

You can pass connections to whatever backend server/port you want.

But I see there is a bunch of stuff missing from your setup.

So this is from my own HAProxy setup, with which I forward https connections that must share a global IPv4 address, to backend servers which all have unique global IPv6 (and unique private IPv4).

```
frontend https
    bind :443
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
    tcp-request content accept if { req.ssl_hello_type 1 }

    use_backend goren_example_com if { req_ssl_sni -i awx.example.com }
    use_backend goren_example_com if { req_ssl_sni -i goren.example.com }
    use_backend goren_example_com if { req_ssl_sni -i tower.example.com }

backend goren_example_com
    server goren 192.168.101.182:443 send-proxy-v2
```

Note that I am doing SNI inspection here, and matching on the SNI hostname to determine which backend to send the connection to.

Then I use `send-proxy-v2` which enables the [PROXY protocol](http://www.haproxy.org/download/1.5/doc/proxy-protocol.txt) on the backend connection. This will let me tell the backend the IP address where the connection originated. We use this protocol because `X-Forwarded-For` is not possible in this setup.

But the PROXY protocol does require the backend server to be aware of it. To make that happen required a small change in my nginx setup, to wit:

```
listen 443 ssl http2 proxy_protocol;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
set_real_ip_from 192.168.101.1;
real_ip_header proxy_protocol;
```

By specifying `proxy_protocol` in `listen` and `real_ip_header`, nginx now knows to get the real IP address of the client via PROXY protocol. (And notice that I do not use it on the IPv6 listener, because I only proxy IPv4 connections via haproxy. IPv6 connections come in directly, and a proxy is not required. This is one big advantage of IPv6.)

Finally, older versions of nginx spoke version 1 of the PROXY protocol, so if `send-proxy-v2` in `haproxy.cfg` doesn't work, you'll need to change it to `send-proxy`.

(And if you're one of the people still using Apache, set [`RemoteIPProxyProtocol on`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_remoteip.html#remoteipproxyprotocol).)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to keep my question simple. SNI on frontend is not the problem. I tried send-proxy-v2, but i have no control over webserver for www.example.com. server web1 www.example.com:443 sni str(www.example.com) verify none send-proxy-v2 still sends me to default webpage. Without https i can do:  http-request set-uri https://www.example.com%[path]?%[query]

Comment: @RalfViellieber Using the PROXY protocol is optional. You don't have to do it, but the backend web server will see HAProxy's IP address instead of the client's. And the hostname is passed in SNI; there's nothing to do there. You can't modify this traffic like you do with HTTP.

Comment: Please see my complement in my question, i don‘t have different private IPs for the backend servers

Comment: @RalfViellieber I don't understand why you made that comment. This example already covers sending multiple hostnames to the same backend IP address.

Comment: server spearhead 192.168.101.64:443, 
server goren 192.168.101.182:443, 
server redmine 192.168.101.241:443 are different private IPs?!

Comment: @RalfViellieber Yes, but you don't have to do that, because you don't have multiple different backend servers. Don't use the parts that aren't relevant to you.

Comment: maybe i have just one server, but my provider has many (with this IP). I want to get my server www.example.com, not default_webserver from my provider

Comment: @RalfViellieber What are you talking about?

Comment: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI

Comment: @RalfViellieber That's just a link to something I already know. It doesn't explain what you're talking about.

Comment: ok, complete problem. I have a webserver hosted somewhere. This one shares its IP with other webservers (vhosts). I have an application with a hardcoded url to this vhost e.g. www.example.com/calculate.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88642/discussion-between-ralf-viellieber-and-michael-hampton).

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. HAProxy ignores every sni str(www.example.com) in tcp mode. (I think sni str() is for termination and encrypt SSL again)
But in tcp mode you WILL reach www.example.com and not the default server when client calls www.example.com. My real problem was testing with www2.example.com is not possible. (And this was a production environment, so i cant test it)